Making calculations in a HTML table
I have a created a HTML table which is editable.
The table contains some cells are predefined with the numbers 1-5, than there is section where the user can enter data and in the last column there should be the result of the data of the previous cells. Now I want the add a formula like you have for instances with Excel. How I can make calculations in the HTML table with Javascript or any other method?
Details table
enter image description here
Column 1: packages is predefined
Column 2: here user can add weight in kg
Column 3: user adds here the length
Column 4: user adds here the width
Column 5: user adds here height
Column 6: user adds split (%)
Column 7: Volume weight = result formule is:length x width x height  x 200
HTML table + script


function calculateVolumeWeight() {
            let totalSplit = 0;
            const errorElement = document.getElementById('error');
            errorElement.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous errors

            for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                // Get input values
                const length = parseFloat(document.getElementById(`length${i}`).value) || 0;
                const width = parseFloat(document.getElementById(`width${i}`).value) || 0;
                const height = parseFloat(document.getElementById(`height${i}`).value) || 0;
                const split = parseFloat(document.getElementById(`split${i}`).value) || 0;

                // Calculate volume weight
                const volumeWeight = (length * width * height) / 200;

                // Display volume weight
                document.getElementById(`volumeWeight${i}`).innerText = volumeWeight.toFixed(2);

                // Accumulate split percentages
                totalSplit += split;
            }

            // Validate the total split
            if (totalSplit !== 100) {
                errorElement.innerHTML = "Error: The total split percentage must equal 100%.";
            } else {
                errorElement.innerHTML = "Total split is correct.";
            }
        }

        // Add event listeners to all input fields
        document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
            input.addEventListener('input', calculateVolumeWeight);
});
table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #error {
            color: red;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Auto-Calculate Packaging Table</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Top 3 Packaging in Use</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Packages</th>
                <th>Weight (kg)</th>
                <th>Length (cm)</th>
                <th>Width (cm)</th>
                <th>Height (cm)</th>
                <th>Split (%)</th>
                <th>*Volume Weight</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="weight1" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="length1" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="width1" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="height1" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="split1" step="any"></td>
                <td><span id="volumeWeight1">0</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="weight2" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="length2" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="width2" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="height2" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="split2" step="any"></td>
                <td><span id="volumeWeight2">0</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="weight3" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="length3" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="width3" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="height3" step="any"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="split3" step="any"></td>
                <td><span id="volumeWeight3">0</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p id="error"></p>
  </body>
</html>



What I tried
I did some research and many posts mention adding javascript to make calculations. I wrote the above code, the split percentage needs te be 100 % and all the fields needs to be filled. Which should results in a result in volume weight but nothing happends.

Please [edit] your question to show what you tried and we can go from there.

Yes, you'll definitely need JavaScript. However unless someone is feeling overly generous, your question is too broad and doesn't show any effort from you to write the code to do what you described

you need to use javascript for this, basically check for focus out events on the cells and when that happen do X calculations, and if the cell is empty, then do nothing. You need to check other stuff aswell, like replace undefined values to 0, and validate that the user can only put numbers...

"but nothing happends." The volume weight is calculated when I run the current code. Are there any errors in your dev console? What steps have you taken to debug it?

@mykaf when you go to my form and go the question "top 3 packaging in use" the table is there. I can fill everything in but there are no results at the final column volume weight. Here is the link of my form: https://strategic-selling.logistieke-baan.nl/?fluent-form=3. When I look in the dev console I only get an error regarding the image attached in the question.

The table in question is not immediately found at that link and I'm not going to go poking around to find it. The code your posted here seems to work. What steps have you taken to debug it?

You could iterate over the table rows and tabulate like so


const recalculate = (ev) => {

   document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr').forEach(row => {
   
      const cells = row.children;

      //  formule is:length x width x height x 200

      let length = Number(cells.item(2).innerText);
      let width = Number(cells.item(3).innerText);
      let height = Number(cells.item(4).innerText);

      row.lastElementChild.innerText = length * width * height * 200;
   });

};

document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("input",recalculate);
});
table td {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
  <table>
    <caption>
      <p><strong>Volume weight = L X W X H * 200</strong></p>
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Packages</th>
        <th>Weight (kg)</th>
        <th>
          <p>Length (cm)</p>
        </th>
        <th>Width (cm)</th>
        <th>Height (cm)</th>
        <th>Split (%)</th>
        <th>*Volume weight</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>




Small change, but OP doesn't seem to be looking for a running total. Volume weight = L X W X H * 200

thank you. I modified the formula thusly
